# How can I unit test for MySQL database with Play 2.x?

Tags: mysql, database, unit-testing, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I need to test if my code creates the correct database statements. I know I can run my application with an in memory database. It's not perfect, but enough for this project. My SQL contains MySQL specific stuff.

When I run my test it breaks on the evolution that contains the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `Beaches` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
```

How to solve the problems with the MySQL specific syntax?

Comment: "Is there a jdbc mock library" did you mean mock for model classes so it will be possible to use models without real database? Then general-purpose moch libraries such as mockito can be used.

Comment: No, I mean one that will mock the jdbc connection. So that I can ask which SQL statements were executed and possibly influence the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a way to get around (most) of the MySQL specific stuff (question 1.)

```
running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = 
  inMemoryDatabase(options=Map("MODE" -> "MySQL")))) {

  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("""
        CREATE TABLE `Beaches` (
          `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        )
        /*! ENGINE=InnoDB; */
        /*! COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' */
        """
    ).execute()
    ok
  }
}
```

Note that H2 has a `MODE=MySQL` as described in the [Working with the in-memory H2 database](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Developing-with-the-H2-Database) section of the Play documentation.

The other part are the c-style comments as described in the [Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html) section of the MySQL documentation.