# DdlGenerator constructor needs no arguments?

Tags: database, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

I wanted to unit test my database operation and I found [this code](https://gist.github.com/nboire/2819920). However, I get the followin error:

```
[CityGame] $ test
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to /Users/pmichna/Documents/code/citygame/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[error] /Users/pmichna/Documents/code/citygame/test/models/BaseModelTest.java:31: error: constructor DdlGenerator in class DdlGenerator cannot be applied to given types;
[error]         ddl = new DdlGenerator((SpiEbeanServer) server, new MySqlPlatform(), config);
[error]               ^
[error]   required: no arguments
[error]   found: SpiEbeanServer,MySqlPlatform,ServerConfig
[error]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[error] 1 error
[error] (test:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 2013-12-17 00:21:23
```

Has the implementation of `DdlGenerator` changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the implementation has changed. The constructor takes no argument but instead there is a `setup()` method that should be used. This lead to something like this :

```java
EbeanServer server = Ebean.getServer(serverName);
ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
DdlGenerator ddl = new DdlGenerator();
ddl.setup((SpiEbeanServer) server, new MySqlPlatform(), config);
```

Comment: Thanks! Where do you find this information? I looked through Ebean JacaDoc and couldn't anything...

Comment: I looked at the source code of play.  It uses the `DdlGenerator` to initiate the evolutions scripts. See here : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-ebean/src/main/java/play/db/ebean/EbeanPlugin.java#L114